# Unable to view the contents of the /etc/environment file

Tags: networking, command-line, bash, environment-variables, vim

Unable to see the contents of my '/etc/environment' file. I have tried using Vi and vim but still unable to see the contents .
I wanted to add some commands in /environment file to $PATH for which I needed to see the contents of the file. Actually I was attempting to add the path variable using

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

but it shows the following error:

```
/sbin : not a valid identifier
```

Can anyone tell me how can I add the :/sbin to the $PATH variable and also how to check the contents of the /etc/environment file?

Comment: Have you tried this from terminal $ `sudo cat /etc/environment`  ?

Comment: I tried as root user . As I am not a sudo user so sudo didn't work for me, and doing cat from root didn't show anything.

Comment: Oh, as I look at it, you don't need sudo.  And if cat /etc/environment is displaying nothing then most likely there is nothing in that file.  Try $ `nano /etc/environment` and see if the file is empty.

Comment: Yeah.. That works for me for the path. But I am not able to see the contents environment file using nano, as was same with vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set path variable in .bashrc

1. nano ~/.bashrc   **note**: user can edit this file no sudo needed
2. go to bottom of file
3. add line like `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin`
4. CTRL-X (exit nano)
5. save modified file -- type Y

open a new terminal and do
$ `echo $PATH`
You should see the added path.

Also you can use $ `cat /etc/environment` to view